# How do you sum a series when individual elements themselves may be series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

Okay Math SE, I've got a problem to fry your brains over. Let's see who can get this.

Consider this:

A cube exists in the euclidean space, it seemingly has the power to divide itself into a copy. But it can only do so eight times. Any copy of the cube generated also has this ability but its ability is **weaker than the original cube**. This means that if the original cube has the ability to divide 8 times, a copy of it has the power to divide 7 times. **Any copy of a clone cube carries over the same ability weakened with a one less value of multiplicity than the original clone cube**. **A very important rule is that any cube, no matter clone or original, loses a bit of its power after a single go of division**. **That is, the original cube after dividing once will have the ability to divide 7 more times again but any clone it produces afterwards will have one less from that number, that is 7-1 = 6 allowed to be created. A cloned copy of the cube the first time can divide 7 times more, any clones of it again can divide 6 times from then on**

Math SE, how many cubes are there in total after all the divisions are complete (excluding the original cube)?

PS: **Huge** hint in the title (use it at your own risk though, **may** be applicable **OR** **may** be misleading) Also if someone can suggest a better title or perhaps edit it in (rather than a "brainteaser yaay"), I would welcome it.

I would like to see how you came to a solution, your approaches and most importantly, just because someone gave a good answer and it differs from your answer, please dont stop yourself from posting your answer anyways. Your answer might be the right one!

**If people are finding this too challenging I can give a hint**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single 8-cube turns into two 7-cubes, which turn into four 6-cubes, into eight 5-cubes, and so on, giving finally $2^8 = 256$ 0-cubes (i.e. just cubes).

Comment: You got it pretty quick! I guess it was too easy!